# When making a custom Maven plugin, which comes first, execute() or parameters?

Tags: java, constructor, maven-2, maven-plugin

So I have a custom maven plugin that has some parameters that I use as global variables. Like so:

```
/**
 * Parameter used keep the name of a file
 * @parameter expression="${filename}" @require
 */
String filename;
```

**NOTE**: This is the exact syntax. Which I'm pretty sure is right from my research.

Of course, if this was a regular Java program and you were to print `String filename` right after the line above, you would get an error because it wasn't initialized. It has  no value.

From my understanding from the maven plugin standpoint, when you put the `@parameter` and the `@expression`, whatever value in the `pom.xml` setup for that plugin under the `<filename>` tab is now set to the object `filename` within the Java program (or maven plugin).

So my question is which comes first? Does maven set the parameters within the Java plugin, or does it call the `execute()` method first?

Reason is, I need to use that `filename` string within the `execute()` method.
I hope I explained that well.

Answer (score 3):

You are completely safe to use the properties in the `execute` method. The properties has been initialized at that time, that's the whole point.